# How to add Share button to every blog post in Docusaurus?

Tags: docusaurus

Is there a way to add Share button to every blog post in Docusaurus using the docusaurus.config.js?

Comment: where you want share button to be exactly?

Comment: at the bottom of each blog post

Answer (score 1):

You can use docusaurus Swizzling. Swizzle `DocItem` component - this will generate react component. Then put your share button where needed.
It will look something like this:

```js
// This is autogenerated code after you swizzle DocItem
export default function DocItem(props) {
  const { content: DocContent } = props;
  const { frontMatter } = DocContent;
  const { id, title } = frontMatter;

  const docHtmlClassName = `docs-doc-id-${props.content.metadata.unversionedId}`;
  return (
    <HtmlClassNameProvider className={docHtmlClassName}>
      <DocItemMetadata {...props} />
      <DocItemContent {...props} /> <!-- blog post content -->
      <YourShareButton/> <!-- put you code here -->
    </HtmlClassNameProvider>
  );
}
```